# laravel controller restfull and form

Tags: rest, authentication, laravel, laravel-routing

i want to post a sign up form with restfull syntax "auth/inscription" but it doesnt work, it gives me this error

```
InvalidArgumentException 
Route [auth/inscription] not defined.
```

route:

```
 Route::controller('auth', 'AuthController');
```

controller:

```
public function postInscription()
{
    if ($this->create_validation->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('auth/inscription')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($this->create_validation->errors());
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->user_gestion->store();

        return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('ok','L\'utilisateur a bien été créé.');
    } 
}
```

inscription.blade.php:
(only the line that we need)

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'auth/inscription', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal         panel')) }}
```

so, error:

```
InvalidArgumentException 
Route [auth/inscription] not defined.
```

don't understand...
can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because 'auth/subscription' isn't a named route.

You can either pass an array of names/methods in the third argument of your controller's route.

OR

Just change the line to:

```
return Redirect::to('auth/inscription');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error may be in your  return statement after a failed inscription. Do you have defined a getInscription-Method you can Redirect your user?

```
return Redirect::route('auth/inscription')
```

Comment: yes , here it is: public function getInscription(){ return View::make('inscription'); }